# Concatenating features to word embedding at the input layer during run time

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, feature-extraction

Suppose I obtain an input matrix after embedding lookup which looks like:

[ [[`0.5, 0.25, 0.47, 0.86`], [`0.8. 0.12, 0.63, 0.97`], [`0.7, 0.47, 0.32, 0.01`]], ..., [[...]] ] i.,e each embedding is of dim = 4 and sentence length be 3 as given in the mentioned case.

How can we append a feature vector of dim say 2, corresponding to each word in the sentence dynamically (i.e, during run time) using the placeholder in Tensorflow/TFLearn or Theano? So `final input will be of dim = embedding_dim + feature_dim.`

P.S: Input matrix is a 3D tensor of shape [x y z], x = No. of sentences in batch, y = No. of words in the sentences (including padding). z = Embedding dimension. Final shape would be [x y z+2].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tensorflow you can create a placeholder of the desired shape [x, y, 2] and then concatenate it to the input Tensor using tf.concat. Assuming 'inputs' is your [x, y, z] embedding Tensor, you can do something like this:

```
features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [x, y, 2])
new_inputs = tf.concat(2, [inputs, features]) # Concatenate along the 3rd dimension
```

Comment: If the features is common across all words in the sentence, how can I achieve the same without repeating the feature. So, what I mean is that I have a feature of dim 2 for a sentence (which is common across all words in the sentence). I wish to optimize the space, so that I do not repeat the feature for all 'y' words in the sentence.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without modifying the rnn or cell code... if anyone knows better, please correct me. If having a smaller placeholder would help your space/memory constraint, you can change your placeholder to be [x,2] and then tile it in the concatenation... tf.concat(2, [inputs, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(features,1), [1,y,1]])